# Setup of Tridion on cloud, do we require domain controller for user creation

Tags: 2011

When setting up a Tridion environment on cloud, do we require domain controller for user creation? If no, then how we can achieve this?

Comment: But we have to host our CMS on AWS and then in that case how we can use domain controller..?and also here my scenerio is that all my CMS, CDS and Broker database server will be on Cloud, so will this work and what users need to add like MTS user or other local users

Answer (score 9):

No, you don't need a Domain Controller - you can use local users instead. I obviously recommend that you do USE a domain controller for user management, as it will make your life a lot easier, especially in scenarios where you need to scale up.